# Tracking Visitor LatLng with Wordpress using JS, PHP. How to put data which was extract using JS into DB

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, database, jquery

Case: I tried to implement via js a geolocation tracker (not an IP Tracker). The code snippet is under Divi > Integration > Body Tag (Divi Page Builder). Afterwars i build via PhpMyAdmin a table which colums i need like visitor_id, visitor_lat, visitor_lng etc.

Question: How do i put the data i get via my js snippet into my data base table gps_tracker?

What i know: I know that i have to use some php to put some data into my db. I read about ajax, jquery and so on but got confused, which to choose.

Question 2: Lets say i have the php code to put the gps location into my table, where to i write the php code, in the child theme functions.php or in a separate file where i upload later to my host?

One of many Goals: In the end i want to build a map, which visitor location shows up and my truck location. So i can calculate the distance in minutes. So the visitor would know i will be in 20 minutes in his place.

Tried to build something like this: https://code-boxx.com/gps-tracking-system-php-javascript/#sec-track

But like mentioned, do not really know where place the code. Maybe creating and uploading the files in WEBFTP?

Also it would be really nice, if someone can give advice how to start with php progamming regards wordpress, especially, retrieving data and putting data into DB.

Regards,

Comment: AJAX is the answer, jQuery is a library/tool used to make the request, not a competitor/alternative. WebFTP is not the solution you are looking for, and you cannot talk directly to the database via javascript. You should look into AJAX further. jQuery/fetch in your javascript to send the data to the server. REST API endpoint in PHP to recieve the data and do the database work. _Note that what you're trying to do would be considered a breach of privacy laws and regulations in many countries, make sure to get user consent first_

Comment: @TomJNowell 
now i know where to start and dig deep into it. THANK YOU!

Comment: look into `register_rest_route` it'll let you register a URL and code to run when it's hit thats specifically for talking to with javascript